# Displaying only even numbers in a loop, and to make an addition of even

Tags: java

Sorry for the basic question, but I'm a beginner at Java. I need to do the following:

- to make a loop containing 10 numbers
- to show how many even numbers are in the loop
- to make an addition of even numbers only.

So far, I figured out just how to display even numbers, and I'm struggling with the rest. Here's what have I done so far (it's not much, but it's honest work):

```
        for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {

                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a variable before the loop int sum = 0; inside the condition  if (i % 2 == 0), sum the even numbers sum += i;

Comment: 1) "_to show how many even numbers are in the loop_" -> create a counter variable and increase the count for every even number. 2) "_make an addition of even numbers only_" -> create a sum variable and sum up for every even number.

Comment: You have done 1) and 2). For the addition you need to have a variable `int sum = 0`. Then you will add the event numbers to the sum and print it _after_ the loop.

Comment: create a variable sum and in each iteration add the currenct value of i to it

Comment: Thanks, guys, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce a counter to count the total of even numbers:

```
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

And add a variable for the sum as well:

```
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            sum += i;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//put this code in main function
int count =0 , sum =0 ;   
for(int i = 1 ; i<=10 ;i++ ) 
{     
    if(i%2 ==0 ) 
    {  
       count++;    
       sum+=i;   
       System.out.println(i);    
    }   
}    
System.out.println(count);     
System.out.println(sum);
```